# Копировать содержимое файла из сети в строку

Tags: java, android

Есть файл в интернете `http://site.ru/files/myfile.txt`

Как содержимое этого файла копировать в строку?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String PATH_TO_SERVER = "http://site.ru/files/myfile.txt";
    String rezStr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ****

        DownloadFilesTask downloadFilesTask = new DownloadFilesTask();
        downloadFilesTask.execute();

        System.out.println(rezStr);

    }

    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            return downloadRemoteTextFileContent();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(result)){
                rezStr = result;
            }
        }
    }

    private String downloadRemoteTextFileContent(){
        URL mUrl = null;
        String content = "";
        try {
            mUrl = new URL(PATH_TO_SERVER);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            assert mUrl != null;
            URLConnection connection = mUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                content += line;
                System.out.println(content);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Открыть и считать.

Comment: Примеров полно. Ключевые слова вы теперь знаете.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так

```
URL url = new URL("http://site.ru/files/myfile.txt");
URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
conection.connect();
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    if (count < data.length) {
        byte[] newData = Arrays.copyOf(data, count);
        sb.append(Arrays.toString(newData));
    } else {
        sb.append(Arrays.toString(data));
    }
}
String fileData = new String(sb.toString());
```

Конечно же, подобный код нужно выполнять в отдельном потоке.
Либо так:

```
    new Thread(() -> {
        // Ваш код здесь
    }).start();
```

Либо через AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    // Ваш код здесь
        return null;
    }
}.execute(file_name);
```

Comment: Я так пробую у меня ошибка вылезла Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ругается на строчку conection.connect();

Comment: Конечно, нельзя в основном потоке приложения делать операции, которые будут замораживать UI. Оборачивайте это все в отдельный Thread, или используйте AsyncTask и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна например вызовите нужный код в onPostExecute, только обновление элементов активити нужно делать через runOnUiThread: MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> { /* Ваш код */ });

Comment: Мне не нужно делать обновление элементов активити. Мне только лишь в строку записать содержимое файла и все. Можете подсказать в чем ошибки в коде, который я в вопросе привела?

Comment: Строка rezStr оказывается null, не пойму почему